# How to change css image via php depending on weekday

Tags: php, html, css, variables

I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background: url(http://www.mydomain.de/img/<?php
$day = strftime('%A');

if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
?>.png) no-repeat fixed center top;}
</style>
```

which sets my background image depending on the weekday.
Now in my html I would like to change this body element:

```
<div class="image center"><img src="pathfromscript"></div>
```

to display the image as well. How would I set this up?

I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
.image.fitcenter img{src=\"/img/<?php
$day = strftime('%A');

if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
?>.png\" no-repeat fixed center top;}
</style>
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<img>` place another div inside `<div class="image center">` and place an image in its background depending on the day

Like this

```
<div class="image center"><div class="image1"></div></div>
```

and your css will be

```
<style type="text/css">
.image .image1{background: url(http://www.mydomain.de/img/<?php
$day = strftime('%A');

if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
?>.png\" no-repeat fixed center top;}
</style>
```

Comment: With a little tweaking, this worked although I lost responsive behavior on the image. Tried: `background-repeat:no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size:cover;
   -moz-background-size:cover;
   -o-background-size:cover;
   background-size:cover;
   background-position:center;` and a fake transparent image in the div but not sure about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are trying to set the image `src` in CSS. You cannot change the `src` of image from `CSS`. You may set the background-image property of an element but not the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

i see you have class 'image center'

```
<div class="**image center**"><img src="pathfromscript"></div>
```

but you after write 'image.fitcenter'

```
    <style type="text/css">
.image.fitcenter img
```

and why you write
src instead background-image
try this

```
<style type="text/css">

    .image .center img{background: url(/img/<?php
    $day = strftime('%A');

        if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
    elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
    elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
    elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
    elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
    elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
    elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
    ?>.png\" no-repeat fixed center top;}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the `source` of the `img` with CSS, which is something you can't do. Maybe this is what you were looking for:

If you want to set the source of the `img` element, use:

```
<div class="image center">
    <img src="http://www.mydomain.de/img/<?php
        $day = strftime('%A');
        if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
        elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
        elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
        elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
        elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
        elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
        elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
    ?>.png">
</div>
```

...or if you want to set the image using css to your `div`, you should try this:

```
<div class="image center"></div>
<style type="text/css">
    .image.center{
        background: url(http://www.mydomain.de/img/<?php
            $day = strftime('%A');
            if($day == 'Monday') echo 'montag';
            elseif($day == 'Tuesday') echo 'dienstag';
            elseif($day == 'Wednesday') echo 'mittwoch';
            elseif($day == 'Thursday') echo 'donnerstag';
            elseif($day == 'Friday') echo 'freitag';
            elseif($day == 'Saturday') echo 'samstag';
            elseif($day == 'Sunday') echo 'sonntag';
        ?>.png) no-repeat fixed center top;
    }
</style>
```